# Returning a PDF response in Django

Tags: python, django, pdf, popen, wkhtmltopdf

I'm asking a very similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008466/return-pdf-response-from-stdout-with-django). I'm creating a pdf using wkhtmltopdf on an Ubuntu server in Django.

```
from tempfile import *
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

tempfile = gettempdir()+"/results.pdf"
papersize = 'Tabloid'
orientation = 'Landscape'
command_args = "wkhtmltopdf -O %s -s %s -T 0 -R 0 -B 0 -L 0 http://pdfurl %s" %(orientation, papersize, tempfile)
popen = Popen(command_args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
pdf_contents = popen.stdout().read()
popen.terminate()
popen.wait()
response = HttpResponse(pdf_contents, mimetype='application/pdf')
return response
```

This gives me a "no such file or directory" error on the popen = Popen... line. So I changed that line to

```
popen = Popen(["sh", "-c", command_args], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

and now I get a "'file' object is not callable" error on the pdf_contents =... line.

I've also tried adding .communicate() to the popen =... line but I can't seem to locate the pdf output that way. I should add that typing the command_args line into the command line creates a pdf just fine. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: When you manually run this command, is it outputting to the console?  Or only to the `gettempdir()+"/results.pdf"` file?

Comment: It's outputting to the results.pdf file, correctly formatted and everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first version fails because python does not know where wkhtmltopdf is located. Python will not check your path for that. Your second version passes the command to a shell which takes care of that. You achieve the same effect by passing a shell=True argument.

The second problem (as others have noted) is that you call stdout() when you shouldn't.

The third problem is that your wkhtmltopdf command is wrong. You are doing:

```
wkhtmltopdf -O %s -s %s -T 0 -R 0 -B 0 -L 0 http://pdfurl tempfile/results.pdf
```

Instead you should pass

```
wkhtmltopdf -O %s -s %s -T 0 -R 0 -B 0 -L 0 http://pdfurl -
```

That way wkhtmltopdf will write the output to standard output and you can read it. If you pass another - as the source, you can send the html over the standard input.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This has pretty much been a crash course in python file I/O for me. I ended up passing the output directly to standard output and bypassing any temp files to avoid security mishaps.

Answer (score 3):

`wkhtmltopdf` is not outputting the contents of the PDF for `Popen` to read it.  `pdf_contents` correctly contains the output of the command (nothing).  You will need to read the contents of the output file if you want to return it to the client (see below), or skip the output file and make `wkhtmltopdf` output the contents of the pdf directly,

```
from tempfile import *
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

tempfile = gettempdir()+"/results.pdf"
command_args = "/path/to/wkhtmltopdf -O %s -s %s -T 0 -R 0 -B 0 -L 0 http://pdfurl %s" % ('Landscape', 'Tabloid', tempfile)
popen = Popen(["sh", "-c", command_args])
popen.wait()
f = open(tempfile, 'r')
pdf_contents = f.read()
f.close()

return HttpResponse(pdf_contents, mimetype='application/pdf')
```

Comment: HttpResponseBase.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting `'file' object is not callable` is because once you have your `popen` object, `stdout` is a filehandle, not a method.  Don't call it, just use it:

```
popen = Popen(command_args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
pdf_contents = popen.stdout.read()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However now instead of errors I get back a blank pdf file (0 bytes). I can see the correctly made pdf sitting on the server though. Any idea why the "sh", "-c" arguments get rid of the "no such file or directory" error?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider changing

```
popen = Popen(command_args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
pdf_contents = popen.stdout().read()
# ...
response = ...
```

to

```
pdf_contents = subprocess.check_output(command_args.split())
response = ...
```

or in older versions:

```
process = Popen(command_args.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
pdf_contents = process.stdout.read()
response = ...
```

I suggest you take a look at the [check_output](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function.

EDIT: Also, don't call terminate(), as it will kill the process without waiting it to complete, possibly resulting in a corrupted PDF. You will pretty much only need to use wait(), as it will wait for the process to complete (and thus output all it has to output). When using the check_output() function, you need not to worry about it, as it waits for the process to complete by "default".

Other than that, naming a variable with the same name as a module (I'm talking about tempfile) is a *bad* idea. I suggest you to change it to tmpfile and to check out [NamedTemporaryFile](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile)s as it is safer to use than what you are doing right now.

Comment: Unfortunately this call is new in python 2.7 and I'm running 2.6. I might attempt to upgrade if all else fails.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've changed the tempfile variable name and gotten rid of terminate(). However I'm still getting back a blank pdf file despite seeing the correctly made pdf sitting on the server.

Comment: If this still doesn't work, you might need to add process.wait() before pdf_contents = process.stdout.read(). Hope it helps.